# Duplicate entries are added to known_hosts file on every login

Tags: known-hosts

I have .ssh/config file in this format:

```
Host ABC
Hostname example.com
HostKeyAlias ABC
CheckHostIP yes
StrictHostKeyChecking no
Port 1001
User userABC

Host CDE
Hostname example.com
HostKeyAlias CDE
CheckHostIP yes
StrictHostKeyChecking no
Port 1002
User userCDE
```

The hostname is the same but based on PORT# the firewall redirects the access to the correct predefined host.
Everything is working except:

1. Warning: Permanently added 'ABC,example.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
   this happens every single time
2. known_hosts files is keep on growing with duplicate entries

I don't mind the Warning itself, but I don't want the known_hosts file to grow with redundant entries!

Comment: Are you getting duplicate entries for each (hostname, port) pair, or one per port?

Comment: Yes. multiple host entries for each alias e.g.: ABC ssh-rsa AAAAB3etc ABC,IP address ssh-rsa AAAAB3etc ABC ssh-rsa AAAAB3etc

sometimes the entry apears with IP adress of the host after the comma. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with CheckHostIP set to no?

I found a similar issue, and I'm just throwing this out as a thought.  I'd have to setup a test to try this out, because I'm really curious now what's going on.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733753/how-to-handle-ssh-host-key-verification-with-2-different-hosts-on-the-same-but

Comment: That's exactly the article I am following in setting it up.
If I set CheckHostIP to no then the connection does not work at all:

    $ sftp ABC
    Connecting to ABC...
    Warning: Permanently added 'ABC' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    Connection closed

Comment: sorry my bad on setting the CheckHostIP to no. It does not change the behaviour:
Setting CheckHostIP to no does not change anything.
    $ sftp ABC
    Connecting to ABC...
    Warning: Permanently added 'ABC' (RSA) to the list of known  hosts.
    sftp>